# placing buttons at customized locations(say a circle) in blackberry

Tags: layout, blackberry, button

I am developing a game app for blackberry where i want to place the buttons in a semi circle fashion on the home screen.....so far I have seen all the buttons being aligned either horizontally or vertically....is there any way out where we can place buttons at custom locations such as using a layout in android and hardcoding to place them in terms of pixels? Any help is greatly appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do this by overriding sublayout in your field manager.

In the following example setPositionChild defines the X,Y position of the first field (field 0) added to this manager. To add additional fields increment the number in this.getField() and add the fields to hfm in the order you position them.

```
public HorizontalFieldManager testingXYPlacement() {
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager() {

            // Define the x,y, positions of the fields
            protected void sublayout( int width, int height ) {

                super.sublayout( width, height );

                Field field = null;

                field = this.getField(0);
                if (field != null && equals(field.getManager())) {
                        setPositionChild(field, XPOS, YPOS);     
                }

                setExtent( width, height);
            }
        };

        hfm.add(new ButtonField("hello!"));

        return hfm;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are used custom button than sometimes set margin is not working properly so used button.setpadding for place your desire location .please keep USEALLWIDTH for your Horizontal or Vertical layout

Comment: I think he would have trouble drawing a circle with setMargin or setPadding? But I guess it might work with two semi-circles mirrored on adjoining field managers. In my experience setMargin does work with custom buttons, I think you should try the custom buttons here: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276

Answer (score -1):

If your layout is a RelativeLayout you can position elements relative to other elements within the layout (or to the entire RelativeLayout). This directly lets you place views next to other views, and you can apply margins to offset the views from others.

Comment: I think my question is pretty clear that I want it in BlackBerry and not android

Comment: @rashmi I think you shouldn't have tagged your question android then

Comment: Indeed you tagged your question BlackBerry. You've since removed that tag, however with the tagging you provided your idea of what is "pretty clear" does not agree; the downvote to my honest attempt at answering the question you actually asked is not appreciated.